# FOSRestBundle - No Route Found

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I m trying to make a Rest Api in Symfony 2.3 using FOSRestBundle.
I have followed the instructions from here
http://obtao.com/blog/2013/05/create-rest-api-in-a-symfony-application/

I am able to include the route_rest.xml
The DocumentRestController.php contents are

```
namespace Demo\ListBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View; use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;


class DocumentRestController extends Controller {

    // "get_document"     [GET] /document/id
    public function getDocumentAction($id)
    {
        $document = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ListBundle:Document')->find($id);
        if(!is_object($document)){
          throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }
        return $document;   } }
```

I get this in route debug

```
api_v1_get_document                  GET         ANY    ANY  /api/v1/documents/{id}.{_format}
```

But when i access the page i get route not found.

Thanks

Comment: Your code throws `NotFoundException` if document is not found. You sure this is not the case?

Comment: what say the command `console router:debug` ?

Comment: can you post the url you tried to access this by?

Comment: console router:debug is enclosed

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Guys,
I finally figured it out. I was adding an extra slash in the URI while doing copy paste from

```
php app/console router:debug | grep api
```

It was a silly mistake and took me long time to figure it out.